# Indicate Process during Java FX TreeItem getChildren lazy execution

Tags: java, treeview, javafx-2

I implement a dynamically build Jafa FX2 TreeView (of a file system directory) according to the example in http://www.loop81.com/2011/11/javafx-20-mastering-treeview.html with lazy loading of directory children when expanding an node.

When loading of the children is takeing some time, the interface is not responsive, especially when a tree node with a lot of children is expanded, so I want to show a progress indicator. After a lot of trials with background tasks, events and so on without success I am stuck without an idea.

What is an elegant way to achieve progress indicator during TreeItem.getChildren()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution (Java 8):
Create field for progress indicator:

```
private ProgressIndicator pinMain;
```

In constructor, create it and set size:

```
pinMain = new ProgressIndicator();
pinMain.setPrefSize(20, 20);
```

In getChildren method create Task for long-time operation. Before start task setGraphic for tree item, after execution remove graphic:

```
@Override
public ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> getChildren() {  
    if (hasLoadedChildren == false) {
        Task<ArrayList<LazyTreeItem>> task = new Task<ArrayList<LazyTreeItem>>() {
            @Override
            protected void succeeded() {
                super.succeeded();
                hasLoadedChildren = true;
                LazyTreeItem.super.getChildren().setAll(getValue());
                // remove progress indicator
                setGraphic(null);
            }            
            @Override
            protected ArrayList<LazyTreeItem> call() throws Exception {
                ArrayList<LazyTreeItem> list = loadChildren();
                return list;
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(task);
        // show progress indicator
        setGraphic(pinMain);
        t.start();
    }  
    return super.getChildren();  
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sergei, sorry for waiting so long to react. The project meanwhile was on ice since I had no progress and other projects were more important. I could not see the ProgessIndicator at first, because I implemented my own TreeCell Factory. With standard TreeCell implementation it works perfect.